# SELINUX not installing on Hyper-V Debian Jessie VM

Tags: debian, selinux

I'm currently trying to install SELinux on Debian Jessie VM.

I'm following the instructions on the Debian website [here](https://wiki.debian.org/SELinux/Setup)

Once I've completed the installation, I make a change to `/etc/default/rcS` to contain `FSCKFIX=yes`

When I run `check-selinux-installation` I am getting the following error:

```
../proc/1       kernel..
SELinux is not enabled.
The init process (PID 1) is running in an incorrect domain.
```

I've checked online and the only reference to this error that I can find is where AppArmor is installed, but after checking aptitude I cannot see this installed.

Does anyone know how I can fix this or where a better place that I could go to get this answered would be?

Comment: I don't think the question can really be answered without more details. The errors in `check-selinux-installation` are due `selinuxenabled` returning non-zero exit (SELinux is not enabled) code and init not having the correct security context. Useful additional details would include (1) what happened at reboot and (2) what is the exact kernel command line,